# Core components of data literacy for working professionals

Tags: bigdata, visualization, data

I am a social scientist invited to give a 90-minute seminar on data literacy for working professionals in the U.S. government.

I've struggled to develop a concise definition of data literacy, but have determined it consists of four cornerstones: 1) **statistical literacy**, 2) **programming knowledge** (Python, R, etc.), 3) **domain/ substantive knowledge**, and 4) **visualization/ communication**.

In the latter half of my presentation, I want to provide a list of 10-12 critical questions data literate professionals ask, including:

1. Where does the data come from and how was it collected? How reliable or "noisy" is the data (e.g. measurement error, missingness, etc.)?
2. What is the larger population we are inferring from the sample?
3. What is the context of the data? What is the appropriate frame of reference or point of comparison?
4. What are the inherent trade-offs (e.g. bias vs. variance) to the methods used to interpret this data?
5. What's the level of uncertainty with a given model's predictions (e.g. standard errors, confidence intervals, etc.? How do I know when my inference is wrong?
6. Does this sample of data help me answer the problem, puzzle, or question I’m actually interested in?
7. Have your findings been replicated? If not, do you have the data and programming scripts so that another data scientist could attempt to replicate your findings?

Any suggestions, comments, or critiques of this framework or particular questions would be much appreciated! Recommendations on good sources (videos, online, books) on data literacy for professionals would be helpful as well!

Comment: I appreciate the efforts. However, this qn is opinion based here, in this format :)  And, welcome to the site!

Comment: You could raise the issue of models that say nothing causal yet are interesting and useful for other reasons. Or models that say something interesting and important about causal issues but are horrible for predictive purposes.